# Failing AWS Step Functions after Catching

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I have 3 stages in my AWS Step Function:

1. Stage 1 - Lambda
2. Stage 2 - AWS Batch
3. Stage 3 - AWS Batch (Mandatory Cleanup)

Everything works fine in that if Stage 1 fails then it moves to the Cleanup stage. However, since the cleanup stage always passes, the Step Function's final result is always a Pass, whereas if Stage 1 or 2 fails, I need the Cleanup to be performed, yet the Step Function final result should be a fail.

Options investigated:

1. One way to solve this is to maintain a flag in a cache whether there is an error, but was wondering if there is an inbuilt way for this.
2. Another option is to use the Result Path to check for an error but I am not sure how to access this result from an AWS Batch.

Appreciate any advice on this, thanks.

I have added the following Catch block in Stage 1 and 2:

```
"Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Cleanup"
        }
]
```

The Cleanup stage is as follows:

```
"Cleanup": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account>:job-definition/MyCleanupJob",
    "JobName": "cleanup",
    "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account>:job-queue/MyCleanupQueue",
    "ContainerOverrides": {
      "Command": [
        "java",
        "-jar",
        "cleanup.jar" ############ need to specify if an error occured as a command line parameter ###########
      ],
    }
  },
  "End": true
}
```

Comment: I personally think the option where you keep a flag is the simplest one and is the least complex to maintain. Whether the flag is set by you or by a resultPath doesn't really matter IMO. After the cleanup you can create a `choice` task that either succeeds or fails the execution. But I haven't tried this myself and it's roughly how I'd do it. Just make sure you keep the original event data after the cleanup task.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Thank you for the quick response. Let me try that. When you mean "Just make sure you keep the original event data after the cleanup task." is there any configuration required for this specifically? I imagine this would be the default behaviour.

Comment: I mean that you should either pass on the full input event or append the job result using resultpath, but not completely replace the input event as you'll lose your flag. See `Use ResultPath to Include the Result with the Input` in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html

Answer (score 1):

Used below mechanism, credit for @LRutten for directing down this path.

1. For all success stages, append the response to the ResultPath else the previous results will be overwritten.
2. Set the error to the response path on an exception
3. Use a choice to decide if the step function should fail based on the presence of the error element

Here is the end output:

```
"MyLambda": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account>:function:MyLambda",
  "ResultPath": "$.mylambda",   #### All results from the lambda are added to "mylambda" in the JSON
  "Catch": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "States.ALL"
      ],
      "ResultPath": "$.error",  #### If an error occurs it is appended to the result path as an "error" element
      "Next": "Cleanup"
    }
  ],
  "Next": "MyBatch"
},

"MyBatch": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account>:job-definition/MyBatchJob",
    "JobName": "cleanup",
    "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account>:job-queue/MyBatchQueue",
    "ContainerOverrides": {
      "Command": [
        "java",
        "-jar",
        "mybatch.jar"
      ],
    }
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.mybatch",
  "Catch": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "States.ALL"
      ],
      "ResultPath": "$.error",
      "Next": "Cleanup"
    }
  ],
  "Next": "Cleanup"
},
"Cleanup": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "ResultPath": "$.cleanup",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account>:job-definition/MyCleanupJob",
    "JobName": "cleanup",
    "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account>:job-queue/MyCleanupQueue",
    "ContainerOverrides": {
      "Command": [
        "java",
        "-jar",
        "cleanup.jar"
      ],
    }
  },
  "Next": "Should Fail"
},
"Should Fail" :{
  "Type" : "Choice",
  "Choices" : [
    {
      "Variable" : "$.error",   #### If an error element is present it means it is a Failure
      "IsPresent": true,
      "Next" : "Fail"
    }
  ],
  "Default" : "Pass"
},
"Fail" : {
  "Type" : "Fail",
  "Cause": "Step function failed"
},
"Pass" : {
  "Type" : "Pass",
  "Result": "Step function passed",
  "End" : true
}
 
}
```